# How to create database and tables from mysql using PDO?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am so confused with this code. Since I am new to PDO, I need some helping hands to fully understand this thing below. It is successfully creating database in MySQL but not tables. I have no idea what so wrong with this code. Please somebody help.

The error reads:

> Database created successfully
>
> CREATE DATABASE products
>
> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

```
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "root";
$pass    = "";

try{
    $sql     =  "CREATE DATABASE products";

    $pdo     = new PDO('mysql:host=$host', $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "Database created successfully";


    $create_products = "CREATE TABLE  products (
            id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
            type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
            firstname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            mainname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            price INT (10) NOT NULL,
            numpages int(5) NOT NULL,
            playlength int(10) NOT NULL,
            discount int(10) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`))";
    $pdo->query($create_products);

    $pdo->query("INSERT INTO products 
                            (type, firstname, mainname, title, price, numpages, playlength, discount) 
                    values ('book', 'willa', 'cather', 'my antonia', 4.22, 200, NULL, 0 )");

    $pdo->query( "INSERT INTO products 
                            ( type, firstname, mainname, title, price, numpages, playlength, discount) 
                    values ('cd', 'the', 'clash', 'london calling', 4.22, 200, 60, 0 )");

    $pdo->query( "INSERT INTO products 
                            (type, firstname, mainname, title, price, numpages, playlength, discount) 
                    values ('shop', NULL, 'pears', 'soap', 4.22, NULL, NULL, 0 )");

    $pdo->query( "INSERT INTO products 
                            (type, firstname, mainname, title, price, numpages, playlength, discount) 
                    values ('book', NULL, 'johnson', 'shampoo', 4.22, 200, NULL, 0 )");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: After you create the database you need to [use](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) it so SQL knows what database to create the tables in.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you tried to search for "No database selected" on google? Down voting your question due you being lazy!

Answer (score 1):

After creating the database USE it so PDO knows what database it is working with.

```
$pdo     = new PDO('mysql:host=$host', $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec($sql);
echo "Database created successfully";
$pdo->exec('USE products');  // <<---- add this to your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you open a PDO connection you specify the database to connect to. As you are creating the database, of course you cannot do that.

So instead close the connection and then reopen it with the new database specified

```
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "root";
$pass    = "";

try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=$host', $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE products";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "Database created successfully";

    $pdo->close();

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=products', $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // your create table code here
    . . .
```